# Android cursor adapter get checkbox and data of listview

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have this code that used cursor adapter:

```
   public class TemplateActivity extends Activity {

        Button btnSort, btnDel;

        private ListViewAdapter listAdapter;
        private RetailerDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
        private ListView listView;

        private static final String TAG = TemplateActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_template);

            btnSort = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSort);
            btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

            dbHelper = new RetailerDatabaseHelper(this);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);


                }
            });

            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(TemplateActivity.this, dbHelper.getAllData());
                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                }
            });
```

my problem is that how can i get the value of the data from the listview when a data is clicked.

Here is my adapter for this:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public ListViewAdapter (Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // when the view will be created for first time,
        // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_box, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // here we are setting our data
        // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

        TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

        TextView textViewPersonPIN = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);
        textViewPersonPIN.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));
    }
}
```

another thing. how will i implement here that when i checked a checkbox and press a button it will get the data of the checkbox? thank you all for the help.

Comment: why dont you use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` ? it is much easier than custom `CursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on ListViewAdapter but i have the same scenario as yours. 
I have used CustomAdapter class extending Baseadapter and using custom layout. By this way you can set OnClicklistners for every view individually(check box,button,total layout... ).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it in `OnItemClickListener` is this:

```
Cursor c = ((ListViewAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
c.moveToPosition(position);
```

You can then use the `c.getLong(0);` to get the id (assuming you fetched the id column as the first column which is generally the case).

**Second question :(Get the checked items list)** :
You can write a `setOnCheckedChangeListener (CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener)` for the `Checkbox` in your `bindView()` method of your `Adapter`, then if item is checked then add the item to the list, if it is unchecked then remove the item from the list.

Comment: how will i implement onListItemClick?

Comment: I mean OnItemClickListener, updated my post have a look

Comment: where do you see that OP uses `SimpleCursorAdapter` ? also there is no need to call `moveToPosition`, calling  `Cursor c = (Cursor) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)` is enough

Comment: Sorry it is the ListViewAdapter

Comment: do i still need to get the value by doing this? c.getLong()?

Comment: It is just a sample, you can get what ever the data you need  from that cursor like c.getString() etc..

Comment: @Kathleen51 if you need an `id` then see the last parameter of `onItemClick`, no need of calling `c.getLong()` at all

Comment: Of course @Kathleen51 you are right, you can use the parameter id, i have given it for the sake of understanding and simplicity.

Comment: @Kathleen51 for a checkbox: update your database in `onItemClick` and call `Cursor#requery`, i know it is now deprecated so you would need to setup your adapter again

Comment: Sir Kartheek, when i add the checked checkbox from the list. how will i get the value so that when i press a button the data will be deleted. something like that.

Comment: is that mean i will create another onItemClick for the checkbox like what i did in listview? what about for the button?

Comment: @Kathleen51 also you can check ApiDemos: Views > Lists > 11. Multiple choice list

Comment: @pskink where can i find that apidemos?

Comment: @Kathleen51 just ask uncle google for `ApiDemos` they are hosted on github

Comment: @Kartheek how will i add the checked item in the list?